# pdflatex from texlive enters infinite loop

Tags: texlive, debugging

I'm working on a text that makes `pdflatex (from texlive) enter an infinite loop. After experimenting for a while I got a minimum working example, which I show below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
  a
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

If I remove any of the `\usepackage{...}` lines, texlive compiles the document normally. With them all, it enters an infinite loop when processing the matrix.

I added `\tracingall` after `\begin{document}`, and the result is this:

```
{changing \reserved@a=macro:->cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\ETC.}
{into \reserved@a=macro:->cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\ETC.}
{\advance}
{changing \count24=28952}
{into \count24=28951}
{\relax}
{\expandafter}
{\else: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 14}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 14}

\@iwhilenum #1->\ifnum #1\expandafter \@iwhilenum \else \expandafter \@gobble \
fi {#1}
#1<-\@tempcnta >\z@ \relax \edef \reserved@a {\reserved@a c}\advance \@tempcnta
 \m@ne \relax 
{\ifnum: (level 3) entered on line 14}
{true}
{\relax}
{\edef}

\reserved@a ->ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
...
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
{changing \reserved@a=macro:->cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\ETC.}
{into \reserved@a=macro:->cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\ETC.}
```

I am using texlive from Debian. This is version `2015.20150703-2`. The version of `biblatex` is 2.7a-1 (also a Debian package)

What could be the source of this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I can remove the `tikz` package, as it's loaded by `tkz-berge`... Just saying.

Comment: Ok, good point, I have removed the line loading `tikz` from the example. Thank you.

Comment: I can compile the example above without any issue (TL 2015, Linux): Off-topic: `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded here, but it is necessary here at all (for this MWE), as well as the biblatex stuff

Comment: It is not really `texlive` entering the loop, presumably, but some binary from the distribution. Could you clarify that? (e.g. *which*...) TeX Live is the whole caboodle. You are probably running `pdflatex` or `latex` or `lualatex` or....

Comment: @cfr: I've just tried with any (...)latex from TL... ;-) No errors

Comment: Sorry -- I am using `pdflatex`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well, they *are* necessary if removing them allows compilation but leaving them does not. Even if the problem does not manifest for all distributions on all platforms. OP: can you specify platform, version and how you installed TL? (Upstream or packaged, for example.)

Comment: I get into a loop when `pdflatex` get to this: `(/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))`

Comment: Which is resolved by moving `hyperref` last. No idea why

Comment: @cfr: `installation-tl2015.tar.gz` from the webpage, daily updated on Linux with some (older) kernel 3.7.10, installed to `/usr/local/texlive`

Comment: I have added the versions in an edit.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, have you tried cleaning in between?

Comment: Ah -- moving hyperref to the end fixes it! Thank you!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, if I clean first, then the loop appears. If I clean first and remove `mathtools` or `tkz-berge`, then it compiles fine. Cannot say which package is interfering with which

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: it seems that moving hyperref to the end fixes it. Would you still want to see the output with `\listfiles` for some reason?

Comment: @Jay: Nope, I think that this is the solution, but I've no idea, why

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Now I tried again (forgot to kill the `*.out` file) and I got the loop now. Shifting `hyperref` solves the problem. I will delete my comments above

Comment: This document will run without error once you upgrade to etex.sty 2.3 see my updated answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you update `etex.sty` to version 2.3 (which will be reaching ctan mirrors in the next day or so) then the original document runs without error, but with a warning explaining the original problem. I have added a check for this case to the package.

```
Package etex Warning: Extended allocation already in use.
(etex)                etex.sty code will not be used.
(etex)                To force etex package to load, add
(etex)                \RequirePackage{etex}
(etex)                at the start of the document.
```

---

**Original answer:**

It doesn't loop if you do

```
\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\tracingonline2
\begin{document}


\[
\tracingmacros2
\begin{matrix}
  a
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

What is happening in the original is that etex.sty is being loaded after latex has already allocated registers and conflicts result in the counter holding the number of matrix columns being changed from 20 to 32768 and latex dies trying to make an array preamble with that many `c`....

Comment: But where is it? `mathtools` can be replaced by `graphicx,amsmath`, but the other order works!

Comment: The bug/interaction. It is interesting that replacing `mathtools` with `amsmath,graphicx` works, but `graphicx,graphicx` does not. (made a typo above)

Comment: `tkz-berge` can be replaced by etex, and the loop goes away when one loads etex earlier.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is it obvious to the casual user that "at the start of the document" means before `\documentclass`? Some might even think it to be right after \begin{document} ` :-(

Comment: @daleif well for almost all classes, either works, so long as you do it before you have allocated 255 count registers.

Comment: Unless of course the class loads all sorts of strange things. I was just referring to the potential confusing nature of the warning when interpreted by a "normal" user.

Comment: @daleif I could modify the message next time but I've upload etex to ctan twice in two days, daren't do it again for a bit:-) Is there is a class in texlive that uses that many registers?